# How to show that $A \equiv B $, if and only if $A \iff B$ is a valid formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let's define $\equiv$ as "is equivalent to", in other words, $ A \vDash B $ (every valuation that satisfies A also satisfies B) and $B \vDash A $ (every valuation that satisfies B also satisfies A). In other words, exactly every valuation that satisfies A also satisfies B, and vice-versa.

By valid formula, I mean a formula that is true regardless of the values of its atoms.

Here's what I tried:

An "if and only if" statement must be proved in two steps:

1. ($\rightarrow$) Let's assume $A \equiv B $. In other words, $A \vDash B $ and $B \vDash A$.

For a formula not to be valid, there must be at least one valuation that falsifies it. In the case of a biconditional, it will be false if there's at least one valuation v, such as $v(A) \neq v(B)$.

But, assuming, by contradiction, that there's such valuation, we can't sustain the premise $A \equiv B $, because A and B wouldn't be satisfied for every valuation the other is satisfied by. Therefore, $A \leftrightarrow B$ is valid.

2. ($\leftarrow$) Now, let's assume $A \leftrightarrow B $ is valid - in other words, for every possible valuation v, v(A) = v(B). So, every valuation that satisfies A also satisfies B, and vice-versa. Therefore, $A \equiv B $.

Comment: Apply the definitions of *valid* formula and that of *equivalence*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA could you verify my attempt?

Comment: It's fine........

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "has identical truth table as" but isn't it the axiom of propositional extensionality? See https://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Logic.PropExtensionality.html.
If so, you won't prove it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax, but from what I googled, they look similar concepts. Why wouldn't I prove it?! It's my textbook exercise from chapter one!

Comment: Well that depends on the context. My answer's context is higher order logic. Now that you've specified a bit more, it appears that you're dealing with model theory.